# Set row delimiter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, microsoft-excel-2010, openoffice, csv

How can I use row delimiter other than `\n`?

CSV fields contain `\n` and the row delimiter is `\n\n\n\n`, to separate line breaks in fields from the row delimiter.

I'm using Excel 2010, and in need to convert that CSV file to *Excel* format.

If it can't be done with *Excel* then is there any other software which allows you to do so?

So far I've tried *Excel*, *Open Office*, and *CSVed*.

Comment: would you mind, showing a line of your csv and to what you would want to change that. Because, right now, I would just suggest you open this with an text-editor and replace \n\n\n\n with ; or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

First I need to be honest - I have close links with the author of this software, having had quite some involvement in its development (ideas, testing etc.). I have been busted for over promotion already, but in my defense I used to constantly fight with Excel and now I use [Ron's Editor](http://www.ronsplace.eu/RonsPlace/Products/RonsEditor.aspx) daily.

As I said I use something called [Ron's Editor](http://www.ronsplace.eu/RonsPlace/Products/RonsEditor.aspx) a lot and I know it lets you change the line break format for cells and rows. However it lets you change them to other line break formats and from your question it is not clear if that is what you need.

Once you have the file as you want it in Ron's Editor it will correctly export the CSV file to Excel, without mucking up the formatting etc.

I hope that helps.